# create a note and attach it to multiple records

Tags: java, sql, salesforce, apex

I figured out this code where I send id and message via params, but i need ONE single note related to multiple records, not a note for each record

```
   public static void crearNotas(String casoid, String mensajenota){
    //creamos notas para los casos relacionados
    System.debug('Nota creada para el caso: ' + casoid + 'con el mensaje: '+ mensajenota);
    ContentNote objCntNote = new ContentNote();
    objCntNote.Title = 'Casos Relacionados';
    objCntNote.Content = Blob.valueOf(mensajenota);
    insert objCntNote; 

    //Creamos ContentDocumentLink hacia el id del caso
    ContentDocumentLink objCntDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    objCntDocLink.LinkedEntityId = casoid; 
    objCntDocLink.ContentDocumentId = objCntNote.Id;  
    objCntDocLink.shareType = 'V'; 
    insert objCntDocLink;
}
```

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create more `ContentDocumentLink` records. Each `ContentDocumentLink` is a junction between a linked object and a Note or File that's attached. The `LinkedEntityId` is the Id of the record to which you wish to link the note.

If your caller needs to specify the related records, change `String casoid` to a `List<Id>`, and iterate over it to create your links. Make sure to create records in a `List<ContentDocumentLink>` and perform one `insert` DML outside the loop.